# 3 tables to count the item price

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have 3 tables to count the item price, and i need to know total of spent too,

table data

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | data |
| 2 | data2 |

detail

| id | data id | item | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | bag | 2000 |
| 2 | 1 | chair | 2000 |

table spent

| id | detail id | spent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 2 | 1 | 200 |

expected result
-> data | 4000 | 400

Comment: yeah sorry i mean 400

Comment: Edit your question text. put correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT data.name, d.price, s.spent
FROM data
JOIN ( SELECT data_id id, SUM(price) price
       FROM detail
       GROUP BY id ) d USING (id)
JOIN ( SELECT detali_id id, SUM(spent) spent
       FROM spent
       GROUP BY id ) s USING (id)
```